# Why this port number is not acceptable for my localhost server?

Tags: node.js, port, hapi.js

I have a hapi.js code as below:
`
    'use strict';

```
const hapi = require("hapi");

const server = new hapi.Server();

server.connection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 2922,
});

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/hello',
    handler: function (req, res) {
                    res('Hello world from hapi.js');
    }
});

server.start((err) => {
});
```

`
The problem is that when I run this server with port number 22291 it executes and exit immediately  without any error, What is the reason for? 
I am using linux centos 7

Comment: Check if this port number is already in use ? You may used 'netstat -an' command to check the status of various ports in use. Grep/filter to narrow to the port number you are looking for ?

Comment: I checked for in use ports, when I use five and more digit numbers this issue comes

Comment: Check for error in `server.start` callback

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the error in the start callback:

```
server.start((err) => {
   if (err) throw err;
});
```

That will give you the details you need to debug. Always make sure to check for errors in callbacks or you'll repeatedly run into this problem in Node.